# Correct notation for set of matrices

Tags: matrices, notation

Namely, is there a difference between $\mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$,  $\mathbb{R}^{n, n}$ and $\mathbb{M}_{n\times n}(\mathbb{R})$?

If so, what is/are the difference(s)?

Comment: The first two are a bit non-standard for me, however after seeing the third, I immediately knew what you were referring to. I would say that the last is more standard.

Comment: I'd say $\Bbb R^{n^2}$ is usually used to refer to the vector space, while $\Bbb M_{n \times n} (\Bbb R) $ refers to the ring

Comment: Huh, the notes I'm working from seem to use the first two, but not the last one, although I've used it in other modules.

Comment: The three are very commonly used. Though, I would say that the least common is the middle one. There is also $M_n(\Bbb R)$

Comment: I'm assuming that $M_n{\mathbb{R}}$ is for square matrices only, correct?

Comment: All three are common. Applied mathematics usually prefer the first two, pure mathematics the last one.

Comment: @user251257 No, $\mathbb M_{n\times n}(\mathbb R)$ is a very rare notation. **The** most common one is $M_n(\mathbb R)$, where the $M$ is almost never in chalkboard typeface (i.e. $M$ is not written as $\mathbb M$) and the dimension $n$ is not repeated if the matrices are square. For rectangular matrices, my impression is that $M_{m,n}(\mathbb R)$ is more popular. $M_{m\times n}(\mathbb R)$ is also used, but less frequently.

Comment: @user1551 oh yes, black board M is really rare. My bad